# Which route to take for an extension to rails that only needs active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems

So I've been reading tutorials and trying to understand the differences between a ruby gem, a rails engine and a rails plugin however it is not completely clear which path to take.

Say I wanted to make an extension to rails which needs access only to active record within rails.
Should I do this within a rails engine? It seems overkill since I won't be needing routes, controllers, or views just a way to create models which exist within a database. Or do I make a gem that requires rails be installed? and if I do go that route is it possible to have db migrations within the gem. What happens if I just require ActiveRecord? Will others still easily be able to integrate my gem within their own projects?

It would be nice to know that if I do make a gem it is not required that the users absolutely have to have the full rails stack within the application they are working on.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show own effort.

Comment: I've been reading a lot of documentation and such but even with a lot of googling its not clear the repercussions of each choice.

Comment: You need to help us understand the purpose of this gem. It will then help suggest an approach. Ex. if all you need is an ORM, there are alternatives..

Comment: My idea is to create a naive bayes classifier gem which extends the functionality of existing models. You put something like has_nbayes in the model along with options and run a migration to add the field which will be used for training. For example I have a tweet model, with user and body text, and another field where some how (maybe user input) has determined the text to be "good", a generic classification which can be used to train on and determine the class of new tweets that have not been determined to bave a class.